# windows.location.href doesn't work

Tags: javascript, search, input, location-href

I have a little trouble with javascript.

This is the search box :

```
<input id="lala" onkeypress="lala(event)" />
```

This is the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lala(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(tecla==13) windows.location.href = 'http://server:100/Theme/resumenInstrumento.aspx?nemo=lan';
} 
</script>
```

When do a javascript alert, it appears well, but I cant go to URL.

Answer (score 7):

It should be `window`, not `windows`:

```
window.location.href = ....
```

Comment: especially in the oh-so-forgiving javascript ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just do window.location = "....";